# How can I build IB for multiple screen layer in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

[image]

I understood changing corner and disable navigation bar. but i need to build through in xib.
 Now you will get clear idea about my question.

**How can i build my uiview like sample one**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and then change the radius value on the desired UIView like this `view.layer.cornerRadius = 4;`

If for example you have a UIViewController and you want to add two views like above you do this at the loadView method of your viewcontroller:

```
UIView *testView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,200,200)];
UIView *testView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,150,150)];
[testView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[testView2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
testView1.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
testView2.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
[self.view addSubview testView1];
[self.view addSubview testView2];
[testView1 release];
[testView2 release];
```

This will create two views one "inside" the other both with rounded corners.

If you want to make the viewcontroller's initial view appear with round corners do this:

```
-(void)loadView {
 UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
 [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
 view.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
 self.view =view;
 [view release];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
 self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

And add this line:

```
window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

to your application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

Comment: Initialize your view like that UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,50,50)]; and then testView.layer.cornerRadius = 4;

Comment: Thanks. change as  [self.view addSubview :testView2];
It is working fine. But i need to build through my XIB   and need to change my iphone screen as rect corner . what we gave solution is only creating separate two rect corner screen .there is no change screen of iphone as rect corner .

Comment: You have to set outlet for your views in IB. If still not clear just read some tutorial how to design a simple view application. When you set outlet to your view, the vairable in your header files say are, view1, view2, then in the source code .m file you can set it view1.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0 and view.layer.maskToBountds = YES.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Button View on top may be the simple way.

Comment: There is no button View in IB library

Comment: Yeah, it should called Round Rect Button.

Answer (score 2):

Stick a UIImageView in each corner with the correct corner images. Won't work so well for navigation bars, though...

Comment: Finally i got using UIImage view. this is good solution for me . Thanks lot.